# Compare multiple differences in SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Currently I use this query to show the differences:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN PaymentMethodCRM <> PaymentMethodBOU THEN 'Payement Method CRM / BOU' 
        WHEN PaymentMethodCRM <> PaymentMethodFicheERP THEN 'Payement Method CRM / ERP'
        WHEN PaymentDeadlineCRM <> PaymentDeadlineBOU THEN 'Payment Deadline CRM / BOU'
        WHEN PaymentDeadlineCRM <> PaymentDeadlineFicheERP THEN 'Payment Deadline CRM / ERP'
        WHEN EditModeBOU <> EditModeContratERP THEN 'Edit Mode BOU / ERP'
        WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CompanyNameCRM)) <> LTRIM(RTRIM(CompanyNameBOU)) THEN 'Company Name CRM / BOU'
        WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CompanyNameBOU)) <> LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(CompanyNameFicheERP AS NVARCHAR(50)))) THEN 'Company Name BOU / ERP'
        ELSE ''
    END AS Verification
FROM 
    Temp
```

But how to do if there are multiple differences?

My goal it's to show it like this:

```
Payement Method CRM / BOU ; Payement Method CRM / ERP ; Payment Deadline CRM / ERP
```

I don't want to have twenty lines of code to test each case

Comment: WHEN XX <> YY AND QQ <> ZZ THEN 'answer'

Comment: I think you'd need to write a function to achieve this - I'm not sure a pure SQL solution is possible (without having an unmanageable sequence of AND/OR statements to allow for every possible combination)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL-Server 2016; You can do it using [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [FOR XML PATH](https://www.sqlshack.com/for-xml-path-clause-in-sql-server/).

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT '; ' + DIFFERENCE 
              FROM (
                  SELECT 
                      CASE
                          WHEN PaymentMethodCRM <> PaymentMethodBOU THEN 'Payement Method CRM / BOU' 
                          WHEN PaymentMethodCRM <> PaymentMethodFicheERP THEN 'Payement Method CRM / ERP'
                          WHEN PaymentDeadlineCRM <> PaymentDeadlineBOU THEN 'Payment Deadline CRM / BOU'
                          WHEN PaymentDeadlineCRM <> PaymentDeadlineFicheERP THEN 'Payment Deadline CRM / ERP'
                          WHEN EditModeBOU <> EditModeContratERP THEN 'Edit Mode BOU / ERP'
                          WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CompanyNameCRM)) <> LTRIM(RTRIM(CompanyNameBOU)) THEN 'Company Name CRM / BOU'
                          WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(CompanyNameBOU)) <> LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(CompanyNameFicheERP AS NVARCHAR(50)))) THEN 'Company Name BOU / ERP'
                          ELSE ''
                      END AS DIFFERENCE
                  FROM 
                      Temp
                  ) AS DIFFERENCES_TABLE
              WHERE DIFFERENCE <> ''
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS DIFFERENCES;
```

In SQL-Server 2017; You can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for the same.

Comment: Solid, though I'd rather you didn't underline `stuff` (or even mention it at all), because people see it in the beginning and start talking about "stuff concatenation" when it only removes the leading delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply each comparison as its own cross-apply and simply concatenate the results, something like:

```
create table t(cola int, colb int, colc int);
insert into t select 0,1,1;
insert into t select 0,0,0;
insert into t select 1,0,1;
insert into t select 0,1,1;

select *, Concat_Ws('; ', ab, ac, bc) Variances
from t
cross apply(values(case when cola <> colb then 'ColA-B' end))a(ab)
cross apply(values(case when cola <> colc then 'ColA-C' end))b(ac)
cross apply(values(case when colb <> colc then 'ColB-C' end))c(bc);
```